# HTTPS local development: Should the private key be put in source control ? Should it be password protected?

Tags: express, security, https, ssl-certificate

I am running a local HTTPS server, using a self signed certificate. As much as i understand, there are 2 parts to it, one is the actual certificate, and the other is the private key required by the server to set up https.

Currently, both my certificate and private key are in a folder inside the server root, and both the file paths are hardcoded in server configuration. These are also pushed to source control, so anybody who has access to source control would be able to read both the certificate file as well as the private key file. This does not sound like a good idea. Is it ok to have such a setup in a development environment?

Would it be a good practice to keep the private key outside the web root and only pass the path to the private key at runtime?

Would it be a good practice to password protect the private key and then push the private key to source control?

Comment: This discusses a related problem but does not touch upon the core issue of why. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70495/ssl-certificate-is-passphrase-necessary-and-how-does-apache-know-it

Comment: This is a good answer that suggests not to keep private key in source control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471002/storing-ssl-cert-in-source-control

Answer (score 1):

A private key that *means* something from a security standpoint shouldn't go in source control.

A private key that's only used for non-sensitive data in local development is fine to go in source control. After all, it's fairly common practice to do local development *without HTTPS at all*. Someone on your internal network snooping and finding out that "Kermit the Frog" wrote a blog article titled "Blah blah blah testing one two three" isn't a problem.

Comment: Caveat: Make sure you're not using the same secrets and passwords in local dev that you'd use in production. That *shouldn't* be the case, and internal networks tend to be more secure than the public internet, but still.

Comment: In production, would it be enough to pass the path to your private key at runtime, or is it important to have password protection on the private key file ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 My answer to that would depend on the sensitivity of the data. If you were protecting health data with this, I'd want it password protected and a HSM involved. Plenty of things aren't that sensitive.